# Load Javascript only on first pageload

Tags: javascript, pageload

I have a javascript which fires on pageload.

How do I change the code that this javascript only fires on the first pageload?

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">fetch('URL');</script>
```

The background is that the URL which is fired by the script causes a conversion (should only be triggered once)

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by the first-page load?

Comment: so if the visitor visits the page the first time, the script should firing. if he/she reloads the page, the script shouldn`t fire anymore.

Comment: You can consider using some cookies or local browser storage and based on that value control your function call. Please use this if this works fine for your use-cases.

Comment: good idea - have you an example of what a such script could look like?